# sql, join two tables

Tags: sql, mysql

SELECT user.login, book.name
    FROM user
    LEFT JOIN book ON
    user.login = book.author
    WHERE user.login = 'peter'

Now i get:

```
peter book1
peter book2
peter book2
```

Bu i wish get:

```
peter book1
      book2
      book2
```

Database: MySQL
Thanks

Comment: Has peter written book2?  Does book2 have an author?  Is the author of book2 differn't to peter?  A bit more information is needed.

Comment: Maybe post example data from two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with others that while this is something that can be performed in SQL, it really *shouldn't* be.

The following assumes that there can be only one author per book, which is not the case in reality:

```
SELECT x.author,
       x.book_name
  FROM (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN @author != u.login THEN u.login
                 ELSE ''
               END AS author, 
               b.name AS book_name,
               @author := u.login AS set_variable  
          FROM USER u
     LEFT JOIN BOOK b ON b.author = u.login
          JOIN (SELECT @author := '') r
         WHERE u.login = 'peter'
      ORDER BY u.login) x
```

It uses a variable (only MySQL supports this, to my knowledge) to store the author/login value.  The CASE expression is set to return the column value if it does not match what is currently stored in the variable.  If the variable and the column value match, a zero length string will occupy the column value - you could change this to be NULL if you like.

I included an ORDER BY in the likelihood you'd want this to happen for multiple names, because there's no way to guarantee data order without an ORDER BY.

I had to use a subquery, otherwise, the column where the variable gets set would appear in your resultset.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it that way...

Book 2 has an author, why would it show a blank?

Why exactly do you want your output to be like that? There might be a better way to do what you need and if you explain it a little better we could probably help.

:-)

Comment: I do not want to unnecessarily duplicate the same data. I use Mysql database

Comment: @gloris - Then don't display it in your front-end.  The query is not giving you duplicated information.

Comment: @Gloris - I agree with Donnie on this one. The UI should be where you take the "unnecessary duplicated data" out of view.

Comment: While I agree with you, what the OP asks is possible using a CASE expression.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

Each line of a SQL request should be seen as a independent line. The way you want your output implies that book2 and book3 have no author (which is not true).

Since you don't want to repeat data in the author column and this column is always the same, you could not print this column

```
SELECT book.name
FROM book
WHERE user.login = 'peter'
```

you would get

```
book1
book2
book2
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can do.

```
SELECT user.login, group_concat(book.name  SEPARATOR '\n') AS book
FROM user
LEFT JOIN book ON
user.login = book.author
WHERE user.login = 'peter'
GROUP BY user.login
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Won't this return all the books in one row?

Comment: @Tim - Yes. Separated by a new line character.

Comment: +1 because the rowset this returns seems as normalized as possible given the request.  each row has an author and some number of books.  every row with some number of books has one author.  Given the request, it is good.

Answer (score 0):

i have seen this as a common request from end users that do not want to repeat column values.

you do not specify what database you are using, so i will offer an Oracle answer.

you can use the LAG function to check if the LAG value equals the current value, and if so, replace it with a NULL.

Comment: Man, I so miss working with Oracle PLSQL.  Be careful, there are some who will mark you down for providing an answer that wouldn't work on the given database.  But you can emulate LEAD/LAG functionality in MySQL - see this link for details: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/

Comment: yep - i've been dinged for proper oracle answers - which kinda cheezes me :)... but in this case, the poster did not specify the database originally - although i see now it says mySQL...  in any case, the LAG trick works like a charm when available.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your database is structured and the data that is actually held in the database.  From the looks of the query, I am not sure that the result you would like is possible.

I think the problem is that you are selecting user.login from the user table, this will always exist because if it doesn't, the query will return no results at all (ie. the join is dependent on the user.login containing a record).  Even if you tried using other JOIN methods, I think that you will always get the user.login returned.  If you try to change the query so that you are looking for book.author instead, this will have the same effect since the query is dependent on the fact that user.login and book.author are the same.

There very well could be someone that is much more experienced with SQL that can give an answer, but to my knowledge, the name will always be returned.

Maybe if you give some insight into what else is happening, we might be able to suggest an alternative.

TL;DR: Because user.login and book.author are the same, it isn't possible to get the desired result.